# Tkinter functions are not coloring my text

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Below is an excerpt from my code that tried to highlight the simple text insertion.

```
    if totalaxial == 0 and totalflexion == 0 and totalie == 0 and totalap == 0:
        oot_box.tag_add("start",'1.1','1.15')
        oot_box.tag_config("start",background="green",foreground="black")
    elif totalaxial != 0 or totalflexion != 0 or totalie != 0 or totalap != 0:
        oot_box.tag_add("start",'1.1','1.15')
        oot_box.tag_config("start",background="red",foreground="black") 
    
    #OOT Text Box
    oot_box.insert(1.0, 'OOT?')
```

I have tried changing the 'i and j' indexes so many times, but the color never shows. Anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the code you posted is that you add the tags before you add the text. Therefore, an index like `'1.1'` and `1.15` will be treated as if they were `'1.0'` since there is no text.

If you insert the text before adding the tags, it works fine.